# Cumulative minimum value for a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector:

```
c(5,3,2,6,7,8,1)
```

I want to calculate the cumulative minimum:

```
c(5,3,2,2,2,2,1)
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Show people code and what you tried?

Comment: cummin is what i want,thanks. @Joachim Isaksson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you seem to want is cumulative minimum ([cummin](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html));

```
> a = c(5,3,2,6,7,8,1)

> a
[1] 5 3 2 6 7 8 1

> cummin(a)
[1] 5 3 2 2 2 2 1
```